# git push origin master does not work

Tags: git, github

Although, I could commit my change locally, I can not push to origin master

I run

```
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:username/test.git
```

I get

```
fatal: remote origin already exists.
```

I run

```
$ git push -u origin master
```

I get

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

What's wrong with this?

Comment: You can see the values for your currently defined remotes with `git remote -v`.

Answer (score 7):

**2-way to do this**
**1st:-**

```
 git remote set-url <name> <newurl>
```

**example:-**

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/test.git
```

**2nd:-**

What you need to do is change your 'origin' setting.you edit .git/config in your project root, which may look something like this:

```
...
[remote "origin"]
url = git://user@dev.foo.com/git/repos/path
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
...
```

or if your 'remote' is actually local:

```
...
[remote "origin"]
url = /path/to/repos/on/this/machine
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
...
```

All you need to do is edit that file with your favorite editor and change the url = setting to your new location. Assuming the new repository is correctly set up and you have your URL right, you'll be happily pushing and pulling to and from your new remote location.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is older but I came across it while trying to find the answer for an error I was having and I found the answer. As of Oct 2020 any new repository created the branch will be called main and not master. GitHub is renaming the primary branch due to racism with master/slave properties. You will want to type git push orgin main.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there's a bad entry for `origin` in your config file.

Edit your repository's `.git/config` file to change it; the format is fairly self-explanatory, but post its contents if you have trouble.

Comment: That was weird. I did the same thing from the begging, and then it worked this time.. Thanks anyway!