# Git push error: "origin does not appear to be a git repository"

Tags: git, git-remote

I am following the [instructions given here](http://qugstart.com/blog/ruby-and-rails/create-a-new-git-remote-repository-from-some-local-files-or-local-git-repository/) to create a Git repository. All went well until the last line:

```
$ git push -u origin master
```

> fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

I'm using git version 1.7.11.3 on OS X 10.6.8

```
$ git remote -v
```

returns nothing

Config file for the repository:

```
[core]
repositoryformatversion = 0  
filemode = true  
bare = false
logallrefupdates = true  
ignorecase = true
```

I've had to open sudoers file using sudo visudo command and add the following to it (under # User privilege specification):

```
git ALL=(ALL) ALL.
```

Now if I do:

```
$ git remote add origin /Volumes/500GB/git-repository/myproject.git
```

it comes back with no error, but I don't see any code in the repository
(it has the aforementioned directories like branches, hooks, ...)

If I do:

```
$ git push -u origin master  
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

$ git remote -v   
origin /Volumes/500GB/git-repository/myproject.git (fetch)     
origin /Volumes/500GB/git-repository/myproject.git (push)
```

Comment: Pretty common err. Check out this thread for help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068172/git-push-origin-master-does-not-work

Comment: What's the output of the command "git remote -v"?

Comment: The link to your instructions is gone, do you remember what it was?

Comment: Maybe here:  http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes

Answer (score 91, accepted):

As it has already been mentioned in [che's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15439950/829571) about adding the remote part, which I believe you are still missing.

Regarding your edit for adding remote on your local USB drive. First of all you must have a 'bare repository' if you want your repository to be a shared repository i.e. to be able to push/pull/fetch/merge etc..

To create a bare/shared repository, go to your desired location. In your case:

```
$ cd /Volumes/500gb/   
$ git init --bare myproject.git
```

See [here](http://www.gitguys.com/topics/creating-a-shared-repository-users-sharing-the-repository/) for more info on creating bare repository

Once you have a bare repository set up in your desired location you can now add it to your working copy as a remote.

```
$ git remote add origin /Volumes/500gb/myproject.git
```

And now you can push your changes to your repository

```
$ git push origin master
```

Answer (score 38):

Here are the instructions from github:

```
touch README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/tqisjim/google-oauth.git
git push -u origin master
```

Here's what actually worked:

```
touch README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/tqisjim/google-oauth.git
git clone origin master
```

After cloning, then the push command succeeds by prompting for a username and password

Answer (score 29):

Most likely the remote repository doesn't exist or you have added the wrong one.

You have to first remove the origin and re-add it:

```
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/repository
```

Comment: This really worked for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Your config file does not include any references to "origin" remote. That section looks like this:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@foo.com:repository.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

You need to add the remote using `git remote add` before you can use it.

Comment: In git, you push because you want to get your code to some other repo than the one you're working on. If all you want to do is have a local git repository you are already done. If you want something alse you might want to check out some tutorial explaining remote and local repos, possibly starting from here: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Git-Basics

Comment: I want to have 2 copies of the code. One on the harddrive of the mac (Working directory) and one on the external USB drive (Git directory). If I have 2 copies of the code with the steps I have taken (ie all but the last one in the original post), then I am done.But I don't see any source code on the external USB Drive. I see a directory structure with directories like branches, hooks, info, objects, refs, but no source code.

Comment: Well, if you're missing the remote repo, you probably didn't do the `git remote add` part in the guide you originally linked. Anyway, if you successfully push to another repository, it will not automatically do a checkout, you'd have to do that manually in the repo (but you don't have to, because the files will still be in git structures there). See also this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1887474/7806

Answer (score 6):

When you **create** a repository in [bitbucket.org](https://bitbucket.org/), it gives you instructions on how to set up your local directory.  Chances are, you just forgot to run the code:

`git remote add origin https://username@bitbucket.org/username/reponame.git`

Answer (score 5):

May be you forgot to run "`git --bare init`" on the remote?
That was my problem

Answer (score 5):

I'll still share my short answer humbly, knowing that I'm super late to answer this question.

**[Here's, a simple and clean explanation that solved my issue](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bbkb/fatal-origin-does-not-appear-to-be-a-git-repository-306348429.html)**

Also, since I was using the **SSH key** I used the following command:

- **$ git remote add origin
  git@github.com:{your-username}/{your-remote-repo-branch}**

for instance it would look like:

- **$ git remote add origin git@github.com:aniketrb-github/microservices.git**

If you are using the HTTPS URL, refer to the answer provided by **@sunny-jim** above.

Do correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

my case was a little different - unintentionally I have changed owner of git repository (project.git directory in my case), changing owner back to the **git** user helped

Answer (score 3):

If you are on HTTPS do this-

```
git remote add origin URL_TO_YOUR_REPO
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem cause i had already origin remote defined locally. 
So just change "**origin**" into another name:

*git remote add **originNew** https://github.com/UAwebM...*

*git push -u **originNew***

or u can remove your local origin. 
to check your remote name type:

*git remote*

to remove remote - log in your clone repository and type:

*git remote remove origin*(depending on your remote's name)

Answer (score 2):

To resolving this problem.I just create a new folder and put some new files.Then use these commond.

```
* git add .
* git commit 
* git remote add master `your address`
```

then it tells me to login in.
To input your username and password.
after that

```
git pull 
git push origin master
```

finished you have pushed your code to your github

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I resolved this issue

Go to the remote repository on Github and copy the project's repository url.

On git bash type: git remote add origin ***the remote repository url goes here***

Answer (score 2):

Setting remote repository URL worked for me:

`git remote set-url origin https://github.com/path-to-repo/MyRepo.git`

Answer (score 1):

See this is the issue we get because either your repo is not accessible from the CLI or You are not authorized to do that
2nd case is simple you simply request the access then you will able to do that.
for the 1st case if **`git push origin <private_branch_name>`** is not working then it will give the solution in the CLI itself
Just follow with just one step:

1. `git remote add <name> <URL>` .
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/braQH.png)
   `<URL>` can be accessed using the UI of Gitlab/Github -> clone -> copy https. link
   and then
2. `git push origin <private_branch name>`
   Now raise the MR.
   Refer Image.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you actually typed 'origin' instead of 'orgin' :D

Comment: `orgin` isn't even part of the OPs question

Comment: @NicoHaase  it's in the tile, and it gives the same error and this is the first search result I found after pasting the error

Comment: it's not that useful to say "don't make typos". questions that are _actually_ about problems caused by typos should be closed.

Comment: " it's in the tile," -whatever that means: the OP didn't use `orgin`, so telling them to not use it sounds strange

Comment: @NicoHaase ok, doesn't answers suppose to help other, not only OP? Maybe it's not super useful but it may save some time for someone. As I said, I pasted the `fatal: 'orgin' does not appear to be a git repository`  to search engine and ended up here in the first place.