# Jenkins job and pushing new branch to remote repo

Tags: git, jenkins, git-remote

I created jenkins job which creates new branch and then push it to remote repo. Script look like this:

```
 VERSION=0.1
if [ "$BRANCH_SELECTOR" == "master" ]; then
    git checkout -b release-$VERSION
    git push -u origin release-$VERSION
fi
```

Jenkins failes and there is a console output:

```
+ git checkout -b release-0.1
Gewechselt zu einem neuem Branch 'release-0.1'
+ git push -u origin release-0.1
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository
```

Whats wrong here ? I also mention that i tried

```
+ git push -u origin release-0.1
```

and

```
+ git push -u origin master:release-0.1
```

Still doesn't work.

Comment: Apparently there is no remote configured with the name `origin`. What does `git remote -v` show?

Comment: There is: $ git remote -v
origin  ssh://git@xxx/ebpl/xxx.git (fetch)
origin  ssh://git@xxx/ebpl/xxx.git (push)

Comment: And you are executing that command on the same folder as jenkins?

Comment: In the Git configuration, if you click on "Advanced" you'll see a "Name" field. According to the documentation, if this is blank, then Jenkins will choose a unique name. However, in my experience this ends up being `origin`. But make sure that `origin` is entered anyway. If you check the start of the Jenkins build log, you can see which remote name is being used, e.g. after "Fetching changes from the remote Git repository".

Comment: It related to this question [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437719/git-push-error-origin-does-not-appear-to-be-a-git-repository)