# what is the reason of this error in using git bash

Tags: git, git-bash

I am starter in git .
I am using GitBush and entered as following.

```
git clone [url]
git checkout -b [branch name]
```

modified some files and then

```
git add .
git commit -m "[commit]"
git push origin [branch name]
```

But i encountered such error:

> fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

And then there really are some branches on repository

But i execute command  : git branch ,no branch showed
But in vscode's bush terminal,it is well done!.
what is the reason.
Is anyone knows why such error occur?
Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git push error: "origin does not appear to be a git repository"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437719/git-push-error-origin-does-not-appear-to-be-a-git-repository)

Comment: Start debugging with `git remote -v`.

Comment: `GitBush` ... didn't know that former US presidents have a stake in the version control business :-)

Comment: hum: did you cd to fetched directory just after  cloning

Comment: Possible things to check:

1. Are you registered with an SSH key on the remote repo?
2. Is this repo accessible from the network you are pushing from?
3. Is this repo private or internal and therefore can't be accessed?

Please check those things and let us know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible `origin` is not the name of your remote repository.

Use the command `git remote -v`. The output will be 2 lines (if you have only 1 remote setup) with the first word on each line being the remote name.

Alternatively you can use `git branch -r` to show the list of remote branches. They will take the form of `remote-name/branch-name`. Remote name can be anything, origin is just the typical default.

Then your command is `git push remote-name branch-name` (NOT `git push remote-name/branch-name branch-name` as I've seen as a common mistake).