# Issues with Git push, Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, nas

We are using git to store our projects in repositorys located on our own server. Recently we replaced our windows server with a NAS. Since then we have issues Pushing some projects to the git (others work perfectly fine). Config looks like:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = false
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        symlinks = false
        ignorecase = true
        hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
    [remote "origin"]
        url = R:\\C32\\LH-5000 Cleaner FS
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        puttykeyfile = ""
    [branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

The Error message i get when trying to push is:

```
git.exe push -v --progress "origin" master:master
Pushing to R:\C32\LH-5000 Cleaner FS
fatal: 'R:\C32\LH-5000 Cleaner FS' does not appear to be a git repository  
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128) (297 ms @ 2/25/2019 1:22:52 PM)
```

I cant see any difference in the config files of projects that can be pushed and projects that cant. I am also sure that the path i am pushing to exists and i have the permission to access it. The Repository i am accessing is bare.

Any Suggestions? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git push error: "origin does not appear to be a git repository"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437719/git-push-error-origin-does-not-appear-to-be-a-git-repository)

Comment: I polietly disagree on that one, the error message say 'Could not read' instead of 'hung up'. Furthermore the repository i am trying to communicate with is bare, wich seems to be the main issue resolved in the accepted answer in your linked answer.

Comment: There are multiple answers to that question. This can be caused by multiple things, so you need to read all the answers not just the accepted one.

Comment: @Liam I have of course read the other answers, and i am sorry if i miss something fundamental here but i did not have seen any answer that applys to my problem and explains the issue. The 'bare' issue and missing remote origin wich the 5 top answers handle seems not to be the issue. Same with the other answers there. I am now thinking that there is something wrong with the NAS not the git.