# Having a problem with pushing my github file

Tags: github

I am currently trying to use the command `git push origin test` but an error keeps popping up. 
The error is:

```
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Please help

Comment: well do you have a repository called origin? if its called origin test then try git push "origin test"

Comment: no i do not have a repo called origin. How do I make one?

Comment: Actually you wouldn't create a repo called origin, but instead, you would add a remote one with `git remote add origin <address>`, as @ParthS007 stated in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you must have a `repository` if you want your repository to be able to push/pull/fetch/merge.

`git init`

Add the remote branch as the origin.

and now again run the command.

`git push origin test`

For more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15445062/7994074